# problem with registring and hashing the password

Tags: node.js, hash, bcrypt

so in my register function when i call it without the hashing it works perfectly but when i try and hash the passwords it doesn't work

can anyone help me ?

when i remove the `const hashedpassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);` line the code works normally

i keep getting this error: ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: User.password cannot be null

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('im here server');
    const{fullName, email,password} = req.body;



    const alreadyExistsuser = await User.findOne({where : { email }})
    .catch((err) =>
    console.log("error :" ,err));

    
    if (alreadyExistsuser) {
        return res.json({ message: 'Email already exists' });}

        
    const hashedpassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
     

   const newUser = new User({ fullName, email, hashedpassword });
    
   const savedUser =  await newUser.save().catch((err) => {
    
    console.log( "error" ,err)
    res.json({ error: 'cannot register',err });

        });

    if(savedUser){
        const jwtToken = jwt.sign( { id: savedUser.id, email: savedUser.email }, process.env.JWT_SECRET );
        const userInfo ={ fullName,email}

        res.json({ message: 'User registered successfully'
        ,token: jwtToken,userInfo

    });}


    });
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to save the hashed password to the user model as password. User model schema probably has a field called password that is marked as not Null, which means it is required and cannot be null.

To fix this issue, you need to change the following line:

```
const newUser = new User({ fullName, email, hashedpassword });
```

to

```
const newUser = new User({ fullName, email, password: hashedpassword });
```

Set the value of the password field to the hashed password, which will be saved in the database.